# Make CMTime with a very small value

Tags: ios, swift, media, cmtime

I have a small integer value and I want to convert it into CMTime.

The problem is that

> CMTime(value: _ , timeScale: _)

or

> CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(value: _ , timeScale: _)

will always return the floor so that time always equals `0.0 seconds`

```
let smallValue = 0.0401588716
let frameTime = CMTime(Int64(smallValue) , timeScale: 1) 
//frameTime is 0.0 seconds because of Int64 conversion

let frameTimeInSeconds = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(smallValue , timeScale: 1) 
// frameTimeInSeconds also returns 0.0 seconds.
```

Comment: what the output you expect

Comment: the same as the `smallValue` i.e `0.0401588716`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CMTime` represents a time value as a *rational* number with integer
numerator (the `value`) and denominator (the `timescale`) . In order to represent a small value
like yours, you have to choose a larger timescale (depending on
the desired accuracy). Example:

```
let smallValue = 0.0401588716
let frameTime = CMTime(seconds: smallValue, preferredTimescale: 1000000) 

print(frameTime.seconds) // 0.040158
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I also found `CMTimeMultiplyWithFloat64(..)` works if a `CMTime(..) = 1 Sec` and `smallValue` is taken.

Answer (score 1):

I should have put a little thought into it before posting the question.

```
 let smallValue =  0.0401588716
 let oneSec =      CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, timeScale: 1) 
 let frameTime =   CMTimeMultiplyByFloat64(oneSec , smallValue)
 print(CMTimeGetSeconds(frameTime))                              //  0.040158872
```